# Workflow to copy Owner field to another Lookup field - Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: workflow, crm, lookup, dynamics-crm-2015, owner

When CRM was configured the Owner field was renamed to be a Sales Manager. However, this is auto populating with the Assistants name that creates the Opportunities.

We don't want the field to auto populate, upon inspection I realized it was the Owner field renamed and there were restrictions around modifying it. I've renamed the Owner field back to Owner and created a new field for the Sales Manager.

Now I want to copy the names on existing Opportunities (Opened and Closed) to this new field so that the data is there.

I looked at running a workflow, but am not sure if this is possible since both the new field and the Owner field are Look ups.

Does anyone know of a way to do this without custom coding and SQL?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

As a work around I'm simply going into the Opportunity view and doing mass edits on the field and adding it (by User). This seems to be working and relatively quickly.

An additional point to Andrii's comment. For the closed Opportunities I'm doing a data export, edit and reimport rather than opening/closing the Opps.

There's a great site here:
http://www.powerobjects.com/2012/12/18/mass-update-closed-opportunities-in-crm-2011/

Answer (score 0):

Usage of workflow is an option. One thing you should aware of is update of closed opportunities. To update closed opportunity you will have to re-open it, update Sales Manager field from Owner and the close it again.

Comment: Great point, thank you! I'll keep this in mind as a consideration.